# Javascript function on a button generated after an onclick event of another button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script where a user can press a button which makes an AJAX call. Once the call is completed, the button is replaced with text saying "Complete" as well as a new button called "Undo". The purpose is to allow the user to undo the action they just took:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').on('click', function() {
      ajax call 
      });
update.append('Complete<button type=\"button\" id=\"undo\">Undo</button>');
        $(this).remove();
    });
    </script>
```

However, I am having trouble making the Undo button connect to the onclick function for that id. Actually, nothing seems to happen when I click the Undo button.. I believe it may have to do with the undo button having been generated within an update.append from the onclick function above.. However, I am having trouble understanding what is going wrong. Here is my function for the undo click event for a button with id=undo (which was added in the original onclick function above):

```
$("#undo").click(function() {
        ajax call
     });
```

I placed this function just below the first function in my script, but nothing happens when I press the Undo button. Even if I add an alert within the function for testing, the alert doesn't even show.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#undo").click` will only work if the element was not added dynamically to the DOM. Since you are dynamically adding `undo` use `.on` instead:

```
$('body').on('click', '#undo', function() {
    ajax call
});
```

Comment: I guess `update.on` should be used instead of troubling entire `document` for delegation..

Answer (score 2):

I guess Spencers answer will not work.
Cuz event should be attached to already existing element in DOM
modifying his code like below should work

```
$("body").on('click', '#undo', function() {
    ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple on click binding will not work. You have to use the following.

```
$("body").on('click', '#undo', function() {
    ajax call
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '#undo', function() {
    ajax call
});
```